# Unable to get all the records from map while converting from <String, Object> to <String, String>

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a variable  value1 of type `Map<String,Object>` type containing value

```
value1{assetName=Account, assetInstanceName=Savings, desc=asdasd}

value1{assetName=Service, assetInstanceName=AccountService1, desc=asd}
```

when I am converting it to `Map<String,String>` type by using the below piece of code I get only last record of value1. How can I get both records?

```
        Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : value1.entrySet()) {

        try {

            newMap.put(entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());

        } catch (ClassCastException cce) {

        }

    }
```

Comment: You're swallowing the exception. Don't do that unless you know what you are doing. It seems like only the last entry contains a value of type `String`.

Comment: I agree with Sotirios. Also you can use String.valueOf(entry.getValue())

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can you suggest me how to do that correctly

Comment: How you insert value in Map `value1` ?

Comment: Log the exception. Then you'll know what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

From your output of Map `value1` it seems that you have inserting different value with same key. [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) does not allow duplicate key.It will overwrite previous value if inserting new value on same key.
From the output

```
value1{assetName=Account, assetInstanceName=Savings, desc=asdasd}

value1{assetName=Service, assetInstanceName=AccountService1, desc=asd}
```

You have overwrite the value on same key and when you iterate it will give you only last value inserted because previous values will be overwrite by new values.

If you want to insert multiple value on same key than you may use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to store value and add that `List` into `HashMap`.

Here are [different way to insert multiple value on same key](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hashmap-%E2%80%93-single-key-and).

Answer (score 0):

Little modification to your method.
from what I understand value1 is your map containing all the information which you want to change.

```
 Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : value1) {

    try {

        newMap.put(entry.getKey(), String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));

    } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
            System.out.println("Cast Exception occured");
            //or cce.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

printing the exception condition will let u identify if still the exception is thrown.

Good Luck!